# Recover a GZIP file of which first 361 bytes are truncated

Tags: unix, gzip, file-recovery

I have a gzip file of size 325 MB. I just figured it that it is truncated by 361 bytes from the beginning.

Please advise how can I recover the compressed files from it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the next deflate block boundary.  Such a boundary can occur at any bit location.  You will need to attempt decompression starting at every bit until you get successful decoding for at least a few deflate blocks.

You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/)'s `inflatePrime()` to feed less than a byte to `inflate()`.  You can use `inflateSetDictionary()` to provide a faux 32K dictionary to precede the data being inflated, in order to avoid distance-too-far-back errors.

Once you find a block boundary, you have solved half the problem.  The next half is to find where in the deflate stream there is no longer a dependence on the unknown uncompressed data derived from that missing 361 bytes of compressed data.  It is possible for such a dependency to very long lasting.  For example, if the word " the " appears in that missing section, then it can be referred to after that as a missing string.  However, you don't know that it is " the ".  All you know is that there is a reference to a five-byte string in the missing data.  Then where that five-byte string is copied to can itself be referenced by a later match.  This could, in principle, propagate through the entire 325 MB, making the whole thing completely unrecoverable.

However that is unlikely.  It is more likely that at some point the propagation of strings from the first 361 bytes stops.  From there on, you can recover the uncompressed data.

In order to tell whether you are still seeing propagation or not, do the decompression twice.  Once with an initial faux dictionary of all 0's, and once with an initial faux dictionary of all 1's.  Where the decompressed data is the same for both decompressions, you have successfully recovered that data.

Then you will need to go up to the next level of structure in that data, and see if you can somehow make use of what you have recovered.

Good luck.  And don't cut off the first 361 bytes next time.

Below is example code that does what is described above.

```
/* salvage -- recover data from a corrupted deflate stream
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Mark Adler
 * Version 1.0  28 June 2015  Mark Adler
 */

/*
  This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
  warranty.  In no event will the author be held liable for any damages
  arising from the use of this software.

  Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
  including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
  freely, subject to the following restrictions:

  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
     claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
     in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
     appreciated but is not required.
  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
     misrepresented as being the original software.
  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.

  Mark Adler
  madler@alumni.caltech.edu
 */

/* Attempt to recover deflate data from a corrupted stream.  The corrupted data
   is read on stdin, and any reliably decompressed data is written to stdout. A
   deflate stream is deemed to have been found successfully if there are eight
   or fewer bytes of compressed data unused when done.  This can be changed
   with the MAXLEFT macro below, or the conditional that currently uses
   MAXLEFT. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "zlib.h"

/* Get the size of an allocated piece of memory (usable size -- not necessarily
   the requested size). */
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#  include <malloc/malloc.h>
#  define memsize(p) malloc_size(p)
#elif defined (__linux__)
#  include <malloc.h>
#  define memsize(p) malloc_usable_size(p)
#elif defined (_WIN32)
#  include <malloc.h>
#  define memsize(p) _msize(p)
#else
#  error You need to find an allocated memory size function
#endif

#define local static

/* Load an entire file into a memory buffer.  load() returns 0 on success, in
   which case it puts all of the file data in *dat[0..*len - 1].  That is,
   unless *len is zero, in which case *dat is NULL.  *data is allocated memory
   which should be freed when done with it.  load() returns zero on success,
   with *data == NULL and *len == 0.  The error values are -1 for read error or
   1 for out of memory.  To guard against bogging down the system with
   extremely large allocations, if limit is not zero then load() will return an
   out of memory error if the input is larger than limit. */
local int load(FILE *in, unsigned char **data, size_t *len, size_t limit)
{
    size_t size = 1048576, have = 0, was;
    unsigned char *buf = NULL, *mem;

    *data = NULL;
    *len = 0;
    if (limit == 0)
        limit--;
    if (size >= limit)
        size = limit - 1;
    do {
        /* if we already saturated the size_t type or reached the limit, then
           out of memory */
        if (size == limit) {
            free(buf);
            return 1;
        }

        /* double size, saturating to the maximum size_t value */
        was = size;
        size <<= 1;
        if (size < was || size > limit)
            size = limit;

        /* reallocate buf to the new size */
        mem = realloc(buf, size);
        if (mem == NULL) {
            free(buf);
            return 1;
        }
        buf = mem;

        /* read as much as is available into the newly allocated space */
        have += fread(buf + have, 1, size - have, in);

        /* if we filled the space, make more space and try again until we don't
           fill the space, indicating end of file */
    } while (have == size);

    /* if there was an error reading, discard the data and return an error */
    if (ferror(in)) {
        free(buf);
        return -1;
    }

    /* if a zero-length file is read, return NULL for the data pointer */
    if (have == 0) {
        free(buf);
        return 0;
    }

    /* resize the buffer to be just big enough to hold the data */
    mem = realloc(buf, have);
    if (mem != NULL)
        buf = mem;

    /* return the data */
    *data = buf;
    *len = have;
    return 0;
}

#define DICTSIZE 32768
#if UINT_MAX <= 0xffff
#  define BUFSIZE 32768
#else
#  define BUFSIZE 1048576
#endif

/* Inflate the provided buffer starting at a specified bit offset.  Use an
   already-initialized inflate stream structure for rapid repeated attempts.
   The structure needs to have been initialized using inflateInit2(strm, -15).
   Inflation begins at data[off], starting at bit bit in that byte, going from
   that bit to the more significant bits in that byte, and then on to the next
   byte.  bit must be in the range 0..7.  bit == 0 uses the entire byte at
   data[off].  bit == 7 uses only the most significant bit of the byte at
   data[off].  Before inflation, the dictionary is initialized to
   dict[0..DICTSIZE-1] so that references before the start of the uncompressed
   data do not stop inflation.  Inflation continues as long as possible, until
   either an error is encountered, the end of the deflate stream is reached, or
   data[len-1] is processed.  On entry *recoup is a pointer to allocated memory
   or NULL, and on return *recoup points to allocated memory with the
   decompressed data. *got is set to the number of bytes of decompressed data
   returned at *recoup.

   inflate_at() returns Z_DATA_ERROR if an error was detected in the alleged
   deflate data, Z_STREAM_END if the end of a valid deflate stream was reached,
   or Z_OK if the end of the provided compressed data was reached without
   encountering an erorr or the end of the stream. */
local int inflate_at(z_stream *strm, unsigned char *data, size_t len,
                     size_t off, int bit, size_t *unused, unsigned char *dict,
                     unsigned char **recoup, size_t *got)
{
    int ret;
    size_t left, size;

    /* check input */
    assert(data != NULL && off < len && bit >= 0 && bit <= 7);
    assert(dict != NULL && recoup != NULL);

    /* set up inflate engine, feeding first few bits if necessary */
    ret = inflateReset(strm);
    assert(ret == Z_OK);
    ret = inflateSetDictionary(strm, dict, DICTSIZE);
    assert(ret == Z_OK);
    if (bit) {
        ret = inflatePrime(strm, 8 - bit, data[off] >> bit);
        assert(ret == Z_OK);
        off++;
    }

    /* inflate as much as possible */
    strm->next_in = data + off;
    left = len - off;
    *got = 0;
    do {
        strm->avail_in = left > UINT_MAX ? UINT_MAX : left;
        left -= strm->avail_in;
        do {
            /* assure at least BUFSIZE available in recoup */
            size = memsize(*recoup);
            if (*got + BUFSIZE > size) {
                size = size ? size << 1 : BUFSIZE;
                assert(size != 0);
                *recoup = reallocf(*recoup, size);
                assert(*recoup != NULL);
            }

            /* inflate into recoup */
            strm->next_out = *recoup + *got;
            strm->avail_out = BUFSIZE;
            ret = inflate(strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR && ret != Z_MEM_ERROR);

            /* set the number of compressed bytes unused so far, in case we
               return */
            if (unused != NULL)
                *unused = left + strm->avail_in;

            /* update the number of uncompressed bytes generated */
            *got += BUFSIZE - strm->avail_out;

            /* if we cannot continue to decompress, then return the reason */
            if (ret == Z_DATA_ERROR || ret == Z_STREAM_END)
                return ret;

            /* continue with provided input data until all output generated */
        } while (strm->avail_out == 0);
        assert(strm->avail_in == 0);

        /* provide more input data, if any */
    } while (left);

    /* ran through all compressed data with no errors or end of stream */
    return Z_OK;
}

/* The criteria for success is the completion of inflate with no more than this
   many bytes unused.  (8 is the length of a gzip trailer.) */
#define MAXLEFT 8

/* Read a corrupted (or not) deflate stream from stdin and write the reliably
   recovered data to stdout. */
int main(void)
{
    int ret, bit;
    unsigned char *data = NULL, *recoup = NULL, *comp = NULL;
    size_t len, off, unused, got;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char dict[DICTSIZE] = {0};

    /* read input into memory */
    ret = load(stdin, &data, &len, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "file error reading input\n");
    if (ret > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "ran out of memory reading input\n");
    assert(ret == 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "read %lu bytes\n", len);

    /* initialize inflate structure */
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    ret = inflateInit2(&strm, -15);
    assert(ret == Z_OK);

    /* scan for an acceptable starting point for inflate */
    for (off = 0; off < len; off++)
        for (bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
            ret = inflate_at(&strm, data, len, off, bit, &unused, dict,
                             &recoup, &got);
            if ((ret == Z_STREAM_END || ret == Z_OK) && unused <= MAXLEFT)
                goto done;
        }
  done:

    /* if met the criteria, show result and write out reliable data */
    if (bit != 8 && (ret == Z_STREAM_END || ret == Z_OK)) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "decoded %lu bytes (%lu unused) at offset %lu, bit %d\n",
                len - off - unused, unused, off, bit);

        /* decompress again with a different dictionary to detect unreliable
           data */
        memset(dict, 1, DICTSIZE);
        inflate_at(&strm, data, len, off, bit, NULL, dict, &comp, &got);
        {
            unsigned char *p, *q;

            /* search backwards from the end for the first unreliable byte */
            p = recoup + got;
            q = comp + got;
            while (q > comp)
                if (*--p != *--q) {
                    p++;
                    q++;
                    break;
                }

            /* write out the reliable data */
            fwrite(q, 1, got - (q - comp), stdout);
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "%lu bytes of reliable uncompressed data recovered\n",
                    got - (q - comp));
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "(out of %lu total uncompressed bytes recovered)\n", got);
        }
    }

    /* otherwise declare failure */
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "no deflate stream found that met criteria\n");

    /* clean up */
    free(comp);
    free(recoup);
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```